# Simulator working but device crashing when presenting UiViewController again

Tags: swift, scenekit

I have been working on a game that has different levels, that you access through menus. The levels are 3D and use SceneKit, and the menus are 2D and use SpriteKit.

The game starts in level 1 which is an UiViewController, and when you beat it, the menu appears. If you press a button (that says "Level 1") in the menu, you will be directed back to level 1, but for some reason when loading level 1 again on the iPhone, it crashes, but the simulator is working fine.

I have a simple example code here, which does pretty much the same thing and crashes only on the device:

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
import SceneKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {


func ajrj() {
presentViewController(GameViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view = SCNView()
    var jarrarar = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: #selector(GameViewController.ajrj), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    // create a new scene
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!

    // create and add a camera to the scene
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

    // place the camera
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)

    // create and add a light to the scene
    let lightNode = SCNNode()
    lightNode.light = SCNLight()
    lightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeOmni
    lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 10, z: 10)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

    // create and add an ambient light to the scene
    let ambientLightNode = SCNNode()
    ambientLightNode.light = SCNLight()
    ambientLightNode.light!.type = SCNLightTypeAmbient
    ambientLightNode.light!.color = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(ambientLightNode)

    // retrieve the ship node
    let ship = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("ship", recursively: true)!

    // animate the 3d object
    ship.runAction(SCNAction.repeatActionForever(SCNAction.rotateByX(0, y: 2, z: 0, duration: 1)))

    // retrieve the SCNView
    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView

    // set the scene to the view
    scnView.scene = scene

    // allows the user to manipulate the camera
    scnView.allowsCameraControl = true

    // show statistics such as fps and timing information
    scnView.showsStatistics = true

    // configure the view
    scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    // add a tap gesture recognizer
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
    scnView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

func handleTap(gestureRecognize: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    // retrieve the SCNView
    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView

    // check what nodes are tapped
    let p = gestureRecognize.locationInView(scnView)
    let hitResults = scnView.hitTest(p, options: nil)
    // check that we clicked on at least one object
    if hitResults.count > 0 {
        // retrieved the first clicked object
        let result: AnyObject! = hitResults[0]

        // get its material
        let material = result.node!.geometry!.firstMaterial!

        // highlight it
        SCNTransaction.begin()
        SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.5)

        // on completion - unhighlight
        SCNTransaction.setCompletionBlock {
            SCNTransaction.begin()
            SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.5)

            material.emission.contents = UIColor.blackColor()

            SCNTransaction.commit()
        }

        material.emission.contents = UIColor.redColor()

        SCNTransaction.commit()
    }
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return .AllButUpsideDown
    } else {
        return .All
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

}
```

So is it a bug? Should i just trust the simulator? Is this a bad way of presenting a view controller? Why is it crashing on the device?

Comment: Are simulator and device running the same version of IOS? You should check device logs and see what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

UIViewController does not have an initializer with no arguments. You should use this one:

```
public init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?)
```

and provide it the name of the xib file.
Simulator can handle this situation - it guesses the xib, but the device not.

Comment: Do i put that in the UIViewController? And how do i provide it with the name of the xib file? What is a xib file anyway (probably a storyboard thing, but i never use storyboards)?

Comment: Xib is not a storyboard thing - it's an IB file for your view controller. Use this initializer instead of 'GameViewController()'. What is the crush message?

Comment: It gives a thread 10: signal SGABRT, and the console says: Assertion failed: (renderSize.x != 0), function -[SCNRenderContextMetal _setupDescriptor:forPass:isFinalTechnique:], file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/SceneKit/SceneKit-332.6/sources/Core3DRuntime/NewRenderer/SCNRenderContextMetal.mm, line 688.

Comment: this means your `SCNView` has a bad frame (null width and/or height) and there's no pixel to render to.

Comment: @mnuages I made the scnView.frame to have a width and height of 1 pixel, and it didn't crash! But after presenting the scene a couple times, it started lagging a lot and then crashed and gave a memory warning. Is there any better ways to present an UIViewController many times?

Answer (score 0):

This smells like a memory leak to me because it gets progressively slower as the program runs. It looks like you instantiate the scene/view each time you present it.

The timer has a string reference to the scene. It appears to fire presentViewController() on the previous VC. Each time through (every 2 seconds? Why?) you'll consume another VC and scene.

I don't see where the stack ever gets popped.

What does the Leaks Instrument show?